On constructing the canonical boundary operator for a given differential operator
Given an $n\times n$ matrix $$X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1n} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \cdots & x_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}$$
I have a function $f(X)$ constructed from the elements of this matrix. This function has the special property that it is symmetric under the exchange of any two rows. For example, one such function of course is the trace, and another is the permanent. The domain of this function is $x_{ij}\geq 0$.
Consider the operator $O_1=x_{11}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{11}}+\sum\limits_{j\neq 1}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x_{11}x_{jj}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{1j}}$. I am studying the behavior of this function as we move along the integral curve generated by this vector field.
Now suppose we are at the boundary where $x_{12}=0$, and the other elements are strictly positive. As we are at the boundary, we can no longer consider the partial derivative $\sqrt{x_{11}x_{22}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{12}}$ (as we can no longer move in the direction of this vector and "cross" the boundary.
What is the natural/canonical boundary operator associated with $O_1$ at the boundary where $x12=0$? The first thing that comes to mind of course is $x_{11}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{11}}+\sum\limits_{j\neq 1,2}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x_{11}x_{jj}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{1j}}$. However, this doesn't have the nice properties that $O_1$ has (i.e. the function is no longer increasing as we move along this vector field). Perhaps the fact that the function is symmetric under the exchange of any two rows is important here (that the desired operator should preserve that property in some way)?
